# Angular 2 code into existing JSF web app

Tags: angular, jsf, webapp2

I have an existing JSF web application with maven. JSF is used for the UI. Now I want to build new screens in angular 2 code in same web app with rest call. I dont know where to add angular code in current web application. I want to deploy this in WebLogic server.

Answer (score 0):

Watch my presentation where I show how to deploy an Angular app in the Spring Boot server: https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2238

With Weblogic it's going to be similar - just deploy your Angular bundles in a directory where you'd deploy an index.html of any Web app.